# Definition of exponential function, single-valued or multi-valued?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

If we define

$$e^z=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots$$

then it is single-valued.

However, if we write

$$e^z=e^{z\ln e}$$

then it is multi-valued.

Besides, $a^z$ is multi-valued in general. It is kind of strange if only when the base is $e$ that it is single-valued.

My thought:
Is it true that there are two exponential functions, let's call them $\exp(z)$ and $e^z$?

Where $\exp(z)$ is defined by

$$\exp(z)=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots$$

and is single-valued, while $e^z$ is defined by

$$e^z = \text{exp}(z\ln e)$$

and is multi-valued?

Here $\ln z$ is defined by $\exp(\ln z)=z$ and is multi-valued.

Comment: $\ln$ is multi valued, exponential is not.

Comment: You mean $e^z$ is single-valued?

Answer (score 4):

The notation $e^z$ is just shorthand for $\exp(z)$. Everybody agrees that when $e^z$ is evaluated it means
$$
e^z=\exp(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{z^n}{n!}
$$

Notation is not always consistent, unfortunately.

Indeed, if we would interpret $e^z$ as $\exp(z\log e)$, where $\log e$ is any determination of the logarithm, we'd get infinitely many values, unless $z$ is an integer. This is because $\log e$ can be any complex number $w$ such that $\exp(w)=e$ and it's easy to see that $w=1+2ki\pi$, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $\exp(zw)=\exp(z(1+2ki\pi))$. For instance, if $z=1/2$, we would have to assign $e^{1/2}$ both the values $\sqrt{e}$ and $-\sqrt{e}$.

However, as I said at the beginning, notation is a bit sloppy in this respect. Writing $e^z$ instead of $\exp(z)$ is deemed more practical and so $e^z$ used with the convention that it means the same as $\exp(z)$, mainly because single valued functions can be better manipulated algebraically.

As you note, people generally avoids using $a^z$ for $a\ne e$, when $z$ possibly varies in the complex numbers. In the case of positive real $a$, however, since $\log a$ has a well defined *unique* real value, there's no difficulty in defining and using $a^z=\exp(z\log a)$, where $\log a$ means that unique real value. The algebraic property $a^{z_1+z_2}=a^{z_1}a^{z_2}$ holds without restriction, with this convention (but only for positive real $a$).

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong. $a^z$ is defined by $e^{z\ln a}$ for all complex number $a$, except, when $a=e$, for which $e^z$ is defined by the series. So $a^z$ is multi-valued, except when $a=e$, for which $e^z$ is single-valued.

Comment: @Kyson No, I didn't really say that. Usually people avoid writing $a^z$ (except for $a=e$), but for positive real $a$ there *is* a sensible definition of $a^z$ as a single valued function.

Comment: hi egreg, so what do people write for $a^z$ when $a$ is in general complex?

Comment: @Kyson That's not a function, so…

Comment: hi egreg, you mean there is no such function $a^z$ when $a \ne e$?

Comment: @Kyson I can only repeat myself: if $a$ is real and positive, there is no problem in defining $a^z=\exp(z\log a)$, where $\log a$ is the standard *real* logarithm. Otherwise it's not possible to define a single valued function $a^z$ with the usual algebraic properties valid for $\exp$.

Comment: For $exp(w)=e$, $w=1+2ki\pi$. Your third paragraph.

Comment: @RyderRude “If we interpret $e^z$ as $\exp(z\log e)$ we get infinitely many values”. But the following text makes it clear that this is *not* done, but rather  the “principal branch” value of $\log a$ is taken when the base $a$ is a positive real.

Comment: @egreg I'm saying that, in the third paragraph of your answer, you've written $e^w=e$ is satisfied by $w=2ki\pi$ for integer $k$. This is wrong.

Comment: @RyderRude Oh! Thanks!

Comment: @egreg Also, in your last reply, you said the principal branch value is taken when the base is positive and real. Why 'positive and real'? Can't $(-1)^z$ be simplified as $e^{z\ln{-1}}$=$e^{iz\pi}$, using the principal value of $\ln{-1}$? I think exponents of all bases can be made unique if we only use the principal value of log.

Comment: @RyderRude It depends on what “principal branch” one takes. The choice is somewhat arbitrary, except for the positive $x$-semiaxis where $0$ for the argument is at least the most natural one. Why should $\pi$ be the argument of $-1$? Why not $-\pi$?

Answer (score 1):

- Indeed, unfortunately, the standard definitions of $e^z\;(z\in\mathbb
     C)$ as single-valued—which we generally want—are
  consistent, when using the logarithmic $(\log)$ definition of $e^z$,
  *only* with using the principal branch $\mathrm{Log}.$

  I.e.,  usually,  $$e^z := 1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots \\=
     e^{z\,\mathrm{Log}(e)} \\≠  e^{z\log(e)};$$ however when wanting the
  function to be multi-valued (e.g. when determining $n$th roots),
  $$e^z := e^{z\log(e)}.$$
- The multi-valued definition of $e^z$ (i.e., using $\log$ instead
  $\mathrm{Log}$ to define $e^z$) results in $$e^{x+iy} = 
     e^{x+iy}e^{2kπ(ix-y)}$$  being multivalued—which is generally
  not desired. For example, this apparently contradictory result
  ensues: $$e^{i\pi}=-e^{2n\pi^2}\\\neq-1.$$
- Until reading this post, I had thought that $\exp()$ and $e^{()}$ are
  synonymous; it turns out that the convention is that the former
  denotes the single-valued variant of the latter. It's indeed a good
  disambiguation.

Answer (score 0):

You run into problems with the second definition of the exponential, as the function $e^z$ on the complex plane is not 1-1.  In $\mathbb{R}$, it is true that $e^x=e^y$ implies $x=y$, but for example, $e^0=1=e^{2\pi i}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and $0 \neq 2\pi i$.  So $e^z$ does not have an inverse--hence your second equation being multi-valued.

Answer (score 0):

Define
\begin{eqnarray}
\ln z &=& \text{Ln}|z| + i \arg z\\
      &=& \text{Ln}|z| + i(\arg z + 2 \pi n)
\end{eqnarray}
Where $\text{Ln}$ is the ordinary real logarithm, clearly the complex logarithm is multi-valued as it depends on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that the complex map $\ln$ is multi-valued, but in the case of your second definition it doesn't matter, because $\exp$'s periodicity kills the extra arguments of $\ln$, so the definition becomes single-valued and perfectly ok.

For example, $\arg(e)=\Theta=0$ and $\ln|e|=1$, so your definition becomes:

$$e^{z\cdot \ln(e)}=e^{z\cdot (\ln|e|+(\Theta+2k\pi))i}\text{  },k\in\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow$$
$$e^{z\cdot \ln(e)}=e^{z(1+2k\pi i)}\Rightarrow$$
$$e^{z\cdot \ln(e)}=e^z\cdot e^{z2k\pi i},k\in\mathbb{Z}\text{ (1)}$$

**Correction after egreg's comment:**

The following two steps are in fact wrong.

$$e^{z\cdot \ln(e)}=e^z\cdot (e^{2k\pi i})^z\Rightarrow$$
$$e^{z\cdot \ln(e)}=e^z\cdot 1^z=\exp(z)$$

They would be right, had the OP specified only the principal branch of $\ln$. Since there's no such concensus, I am correcting my answer, based on egreg's comment.

I agree then that the definition is multi-valued, and it seems the actual values are given by the last line (1).

Comment: Why should $e^{z2k\pi i}=e^{(2k\pi i)z}$?

Comment: You are right. I assumed the principal branch of $\ln$. Thanks for the correction.