# When should I add $2k\pi$ to polar complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I need to convert the following complex number into polar form:

$ \sqrt{3}/2 + 1/2i$

After converting it into polar form, I got this:

$cis(\pi/6)$

Do I add $2k\pi$ like this:
$ cis(\pi/6 +2k\pi)$
for my answer to be correct? Do I always need to add $2k\pi$? If not, when should I add it?

Comment: All you have shown is that the polar form of a complex number is not uniquely defined. It is true that $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i=\operatorname{cis}(\pi/6)$. It is also true that $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i=\operatorname{cis}(\pi/6+2k\pi)$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z$. Both of your answers are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what is wanted. If you wat *a* polar form, then $cis(\pi/6)$ would be a correct answer. So are $cis(13\pi/6)$ and $cis(-11\pi/6)$. If instead, *all* polar forms must be rendered, then you would put $cis(\pi/6+2k\pi), k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So would $(\sqrt{3}/2 + 1/2i)^{16}=cis(8\pi/3+32k\pi)$?

Comment: @Relaxisys I would say $\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}2 + \frac{1}{2}i\right)^{16} = -\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{3}}2i$ which is not quite equivalent to what you wrote. It $\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}2 + \frac{1}{2}i\right)^{1/16}$ which is the more interesting multivalued case

Comment: @Henry so when should I change $2k\pi$ (if at all) when applying De Moivre's theorum?

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends on your definition. $(\log,\,\mathrm{cis})$ is supposed to be the inversion of the group homomorphism $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C^\ast$ given by $z\to\exp(z)$.

But this map is not injective, it holds the same value if the imaginary part differs by a multiple of $2\pi$.

So now we can have two definitions: We might restrict the imaginary part of $z$ onto a smaller set, like $\mathbb R + \mathrm i[0,2\pi)$. Then we’d assume that $\mathrm {cis}(x) \in[0,2\pi)$.

The other idea is: If we factor $\mathbb C$ by the kernel of the map we get an isomorphism. The kernel of this are just $\mathrm i2\pi\mathbb Z$. Thus we’d have $\mathrm {cis}(x) \in \mathbb R / (2\pi\mathbb Z)$.

So in the first case you’d need to add some $2k\pi$ so that $0\leq \pi/6 < 2\pi$ (i.e. $k=0$). In the second case we’d just get the equivalence class
$$ [\pi/6] = \{\pi/6+2k\pi;k\in\mathbb Z\}$$

Answer (score 1):

To be clear: $\text{cis } x$ is shorthand for $\cos x+i\sin x,$ which is a single-valued function, which equals $e^{ix}$ when the latter too is being a single-valued function.

As such, no, you never need to write $\;\text{cis}\left(\frac\pi6 +2k\pi\right)\;$ in lieu of plain old $\;\text{cis}\left(\frac\pi6\right),\;$ the same way it is never necessary to replace $\;\sin\left(\frac\pi6\right)\;$ with $\;\sin\left(\frac\pi6+2k\pi\right).$

The issue of having to add the $\:(+2k\pi)\:$ typically arises when the [multi-valued definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4132698/21813) of $e^z$ is implicitly being invoked, for example, when obtaining roots of unity, and in this law:

for $\theta\in\mathbb R$ and $z\in\mathbb C,$ $$\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^z=e^{z\,i(\theta+2k\pi)}.$$

---

OP: *so when should I change $2kπ$ (if at all) when applying De Moivre's Theorem?*

De Moivre's Theorem applies only for integer powers, so doesn't invoke the multi-valued definition of $e^z,$ so you don't need to add $2k\pi$ when using applying it. Strictly speaking, adding $2k\pi$ is when taking the $n$th root, as pointed out in the preceding section.