# Expanding $(1-i)^\frac{1}{3}$ using De Moivre's formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to rewrite $(1-i)^ \frac 1 3$ using de Moivre's formula.

I defined $z := 1 - i$, then $r_z = \sqrt{2}$ and

$1 = \sqrt2\cos\theta$ and $-1 = \sqrt2 \sin\theta \Rightarrow \theta = -\frac \pi 4$

So:
$$1 - i = \sqrt{2}(\cos(\frac \pi 4) + i\sin(\frac \pi 4))$$
$$(1-i)^\frac 1 3 = 2^ \frac 1 6 (\cos(\frac \pi {12} + i\sin(\frac \pi {12}))$$

Am I correct with this derivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your final step is invalid (discarding solutions!) because it
  misapplies De Moivre's theorem, which [does not generally hold for
  non-integer
  powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Failure_for_non-integer_powers,_and_generalization)
  like $\frac13.$ So, for example,
  \begin{align}1^\frac12&=\left(\cos(2\pi)+i\sin(2\pi)\right)^{\frac12}\\&\neq\cos(\frac12\times2\pi)+i\sin(\frac12\times2\pi)\\&=-1.\end{align}
  This is because in the complex world, raising a number to a
  non-integer power generally outputs multiple values.
- In your exercise, the goal is to determine $(1-i)^\frac13,$ i.e., the
  third roots of unity of $1-i.$ This process (abbreviating $(\cos
     x+i\sin x)$ as $\text{cis }x)$ **invokes** not De Moivre's theorem but
  **the [multi-valued
  definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4132698/21813) of
  $e^z:$**  \begin{align}(1-i)^\frac13&=\left[\sqrt2 \text{ cis}
     \left(-\frac\pi4\right)\right]^\frac13\\&=2^\frac16\text{ cis}
     \left(\frac{-\frac\pi4+2k\pi}3\right)\\&=2^\frac16\text{ cis}
     \left(\frac{8k-1}{12}\pi\right)\\&=2^\frac16\text{ cis}
     \left(\frac{-\pi}{12}\right),\,2^\frac16\text{ cis}
     \left(\frac{7\pi}{12}\right)\text{ or }\,2^\frac16\text{ cis}
     \left(\frac{5\pi}{4}\right).\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You have only take the principal root, indeed we have (there is also a typo for the angle in the $\sin$ term):

$$1 - i = \sqrt{2}\left(\cos\left(\frac \pi 4+2n\pi\right) + i\sin\left(-\frac \pi 4+2n\pi\right)\right)$$

and therefore the three possible roots are

$$2^ \frac 1 6 \left(\cos\left(\frac \pi {12}\right) + i\sin\left(-\frac \pi {12}\right)\right)$$
$$2^ \frac 1 6 \left(\cos\left(\frac \pi {12}+\frac 2 3 n\right) + i\sin\left(-\frac \pi {12}+\frac 2 3 n\right)\right)$$
$$2^ \frac 1 6 \left(\cos\left(\frac \pi {12}+\frac 4 3 n\right) + i\sin\left(-\frac \pi {12}+\frac 4 3 n\right)\right)$$

with $n=0,1,2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-i)^{1/3}=2^{1/6}e^{-i\pi/12} e^{2in\pi/3},n=0,1,2$$
So you have got the root for $n=0$ only, there are two more for $n=1,2$.

This is like $(1)^{1/3}=(e^{2in\pi/3}), n=0,1,2.$ These roots are well known as $1,\omega,\omega^2$, respectively.