# Taking logarithm of complex exponential

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, exponential-function

Is taking logarithms of complex exponentials allowed/defined?
If I take the natural logarithm from both sides of the equation $$ e^{i \varphi_1}=e^{i \varphi_2}; \ \varphi_1, \varphi_2 \in \mathbb{R}$$
I obtain $$i \varphi_1 = i \varphi_2$$
and therefore $\varphi_1=\varphi_2$. However, by Euler's formula, we have
$$ i\sin{\varphi_1}+\cos{\varphi_1}=i\sin \varphi_2+\cos{\varphi}_2 $$
and therefore $\varphi_2 =\varphi_1+n\cdot 2\pi$ satisfies the equation $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So is there some general rule about these things with complex numbers?

Comment: You can read about the Wikipedia article on [complex logaritm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)

Comment: Yes there are rules. No, these rules are not unique. Yes, there are problems with them (several branches etc) and the easiness of the real logarithm does not extend.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [in general, $\log(z)$ is multi-valued](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4132698/21813)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-zero complex number can be written as:
$$z = e^{x + iy} \text{ , where } x,y\in\mathbb R^2$$
From this it follows that
$$\log z = x + \log e^{iy}$$

Since $e^{iy}$ is periodic in $y$, you don't have an inverse function. However you can gice a set of possible inverse values much like when you solve equations like $\sin x = 0 \iff x =k\pi$. If you consider the equation:

$$e^{i\varphi} = e^{iy} \iff \varphi = y + k \cdot 2\pi$$

Sometimes it can be useful to use an inverse function, then you can do the same thing as with $sin$ and $cos$. You can restrict the codomain for one period only. The most useful cases would usually be $[-\pi, \pi]$ or $[0, 2\pi]$. In the latter case:
$$\log z = x + \log e^{iy} = x + \left\{\frac{y}{2\pi}\right\}\cdot2\pi$$
, where $\{.\}$ is the fractional part function.